# Changing odd (very high) ASCII chars in scraped HTML

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I am processing some HTML and it had some odd characters (which give a line feed when I use the print command) so I did the following:

```
d.each_char do |c|; puts c + " " + c.ord.to_s; end
```

I found it was a character with an ord of 9644.  It seems this is Unicode black rectangle.  There is also a ASCII 219 that looks similar so I wanted to map it to this ASCII code.  I tried:

```
d = d.gsub( 9644.chr, 219.chr)
```

This gave me an error "Exception: RangeError: 9644 out of char range".

Is there any way I can do this (i.e. change all ord.9644 to ord.219.

Alternatively can I change all characters over ASCII 255 to '?', even if I can it would be good to know how to do this.

Regards,
Ben

Comment: Why do you have to replace the characters?

Comment: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a 7-bit character set with codepoints 0-127. There's also [extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) which is an umbrella term for various 8-bit encodings, i.e. ASCII plus codepoints 128-255. Please specify which encoding you are referring to.

Comment: You need to know the encoding of the HTML document. It might have a meta charset tag or, if delivered through HTTP, a Content-Type header, that says which encoding to read it with. Regardless, you have to read it with the encoding it was written with. If you aren't being told explicitly or through specification, convention or otherwise, that's data loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
d.chars.map(&:ord).map { |int| int == 9644 ? 219 : int }.map(&:chr).join
```

If you want to simply replace all high values with `?`, then use this instead:

```
high_limit = 999 # Use whatever integer your `#chr` method can handle
d.chars.map(&:ord).map { |int| int > high_limit ? 255 : int }.map(&:chr).join
```

The `#chars` method breaks a string up into an array of single characters, then `map(&:ord)` converts it into an array of integers representing the UTF-8 codes. The `map` with the conditional block replaces each occurrence of 9644 with 219 and leaves other integers intact. Finally we map the integers back to single characters with `map(&:chr)` and then join the resulting array of characters back into a string.

Note that this code creates a few arrays along the way, each of which is equal in size to the length of the original string, so using it on very large strings may consume a fair amount of memory. If this is the case, you might consider replacing `map` with `map!` to modify the array in place.

Comment: Nice but I am afraid it still gives an error, 'Exception: RangeError: 8220 out of char range';(

Comment: Interesting. I'm able to do 8220.chr without an error. What version of Ruby are you running? In any case, I'll expand the answer to include a version that will change high values to 255 as you suggest above.

Comment: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu].